# pass multiple matplotlib plots to parent and plot them in separate figures in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, figure

I have some function `MyPlot` which computes a custom plot using `matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.
It currently returns the `plt.figure` object to the parent function.
In this parent function I make multiple calls to `MyPlot` to make multiple figures, say `fig1` and `fig2`.
How can I plot them in separate windows with a single command in the parent function?

I tried importing `matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and then doing `plt.show()` but it does not work; it shows no plot at all.
I also tried `plt.show(fig1)` which plots `fig1`, but `plt.show(fig1, fig2)` throws an error.

Comment: Maybe you are in interactive mode (`plt.isinteractive()`)? In that case you can get a blocking `show` via `plt.show(block=True)`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest `plt.isinteractive()` returns `False`, but `plt.show(block=True)` *does* work, and it does not work if I pass `plt.show(block=False)`. Strange!

Comment: I fear without a [mcve], one cannot find out the exact reason for this

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Ugh, when I try to create a minimal reproducible example it starts working again. Must be some strange edge case or a peculiarity of my IDE or whatever. I'll just use block=True for now, thanks for your help.

Comment: perhaps it has to do with the fact that I import pyplot twice (MyPlot is in a different module)

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: this answer is wrong. It seems that `plt.show(arg)` plots the figures for any arbitrary argument `arg` (except `None`), but not if no arguments are passed.

Original answer:

The intuition in `plt.show(fig1, fig2)` was correct, but the syntax is wrong.
Showing a list (or other iterable) of `matplotlib.pyplot.figure` objects will plot the figures in separate windows:

```
plt.show([fig1, fig2])
```

Comment: `plt.show()` takes no figures as arguments. `plt.show([fig1, fig2])` is hence identical to `plt.show(["Hello", "Bye"])` or whatever else you imagine. This might change in the future, but for now this answer makes no sense.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest huh, you're right. However if I do *not* pass any arguments, it doesn't plot anything! Why?